# What's a proper override for all controls to load saved state and store data

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm saving control state and store data to a database (only grids for the moment) and I'm wondering what   listener or method I could override to put the data back in place when the controls are being rendered/shown to the user.

Here's how I save the state and store data:

```
SaveControlState: function (controlItemId, controlType, active, successFunction, scope) {

//Save the control state and its data to server...

var controlState = {};
var control = this.getCmp(controlType + '[itemId=' + controlItemId + ']');

controlState.ControlItemId = control.itemId;
controlState.ControlState = Ext.JSON.encode(control.getState()); //save a JSON string to database...

//if the control has this attribute, it means it wants to update its control state/data...
if (typeof control.controlStateId != 'undefined') controlState.ID = control.controlStateId;

controlState.Active = active;

//if control has a store, let's send data over server...
if (control.getStore() != null) {
    controlState.ControlStoreData = [];
    Ext.each(control.getStore().data.items, function (record) {
        controlState.ControlStoreData.push(record.data);
    });
    controlState.ControlStoreData = Ext.JSON.encode(controlState.ControlStoreData); //same here...
}

control.setLoading({ msg: Strings.Messages.str_Wait });

//initiate request...
Ext.Ajax.request(
    {
        url: GlobalVars.Urls.portalControlStateCreateApiUrl,
        params: { jsonData: Ext.JSON.encode(controlState), action: 'createcontrolstate' },
        method: 'POST',
        success: function (result, request) {
            //hide spinner...
            this.getCmp(controlType + '[itemId=' + controlItemId + ']').setLoading(false);
            //if we had a success handler provided, call it...
            if (typeof successFunction != 'undefined') successFunction(scope);
        },
        failure: function (result, request) {
            var control = this.getCmp(controlType + '[itemId=' + controlItemId + ']');
            control.setLoading(false);
            Ext.Msg.show({
                title: Strings.UI.str_Error,
                msg: Strings.format(Strings.UI.Messages.str_ErrorControlState, control.id, result.responseText),
                buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
            });
        },
            scope: this
    });
}
```

And I'm retrieving all the active control state entries when a user logs in:

```
Ext.create('App.store.ControlState', {
    autoLoad: true,
    scope: this,
    storeId: 'controlStateStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        extraParams: { activeOnly: true },
        url: GlobalVars.Urls.portalControlStateGetAllApiUrl,
        headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
        reader: { type: 'json', root: 'ControlStates' }
     },
     listeners: { load: function (store, records, success, opts) {
         //one this is done, I show the rest of the UI....

     }
     }
});
```

Now what I need is an override that allows me to peer into the store above and find a record, if I have a match (using the control's `itemId` attribute) then apply the state and load the data in the store, if the control that's being overriden indeed has a store.

Any ideas what I could use ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Controls implementing [`Stateful`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.state.Stateful-cfg-stateId) already can use the functions `applyState()` and `getState()` exactly for the purpose of saving/restoring state. So these functions are called whenever a control state has to be changed/applied. I think that if you reuse Stateful, ExtJS will handle everything else for you (reloading stores if grid's filters have changed etc.)

But I don't think that you can do a single override to make states work in EVERY component, since each component type would need a special list of what's part of a state. Such a list is not provided by ExtJS; not even for their standard components.

So I fear that you would have to do one override per component type.

If I were you, I would make a store with ID controlStateStore and a model of three and a half fields:

```
itemId // type string
propertyName // type string 
propertyValue // no type(!)
id // auto-created using `convert` to concatenate itemId, a comma and propertyName.
```

This store would get two added-value functions to load/store a `Stateful` state object into the model:

```
getState:function(itemId) {
    var records = store.Query("itemId",itemId);
    var state = {};
    records.each(function rec() {
       state[rec.get("propertyName")]=rec.get("propertyValue");
    })
    return state;
}
setState:function(itemId,state) {
    // add one record to the store per property
    for(k in state) {
        store.add({itemId:itemId,propertyName:k,propertyValue:state[k]});
    }
    // idProperty id will take care of replacing duplicates
}
```

These are the functions on the store. Now, on each component type, you would need an override that implements Stateful. So let's have a look at the "recommended" getState/applyState functions, which may look similar to this:

```
xtype:button,
stateful:true,
stateid:'bla',
getState:function() {
    // required if you want to save state
    // by default, getState is empty function, so nothing is saved
    return {pressed:this.pressed}; // here, a bigger object would be returned
                                   // depending on the component type
},
applyState: function(state) {
    // not required, since this function already exists and is the same for alle component types.
    if (state) {
        Ext.apply(this, state);
    }
},
```

Here, I would replace them both with sth. like:

```
getState:function() {
    if(this.itemId) 
        Ext.getStore("controlStateStore").setState(this.itemId,{pressed:this.pressed})
},
applyState: function() {
    if(this.itemId) {
        var state = Ext.getStore("controlStateStore").getState(this.itemId);
        Ext.apply(this, state);
    }
},
```

and either add a store.sync() to both, or, the better way, use autoSync on the store.

Although I would opt to keep it compatible by using stateId, not itemId. Since you can reuse ItemIds, but you don't want components take the state of a different component (with same itemId), you should consider to use id or stateId, not itemId.

Disclaimer: Didn't test any of this code, so let's hope it's not too far off the shot...

Comment: That's an interesting answer. I marked it as useful for the moment, and will flag it as answer later if I end up using the concept outlined in it.